# fail2ban regex rule

Tags: regex, fail2ban

just for test, I would like to block all traffic to my website not coming from Android browser using fail2ban.

This is the string in the log file:

```
GET http://www.aaaaa.com/video/09_12_2014_spot_app.mp4 - ORIGINAL_DST/171.171.171.171 video/mp4 
[
    User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)
    Cookie: _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.909922659.1455111791
    Range: bytes=705201-
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Host: www.aaaaa.com
] 
[
    HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
    Date: Thu, 26 May 2016 15:27:16 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
    Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 19:55:17 GMT
    ETag: "2b739f-ec2b1-509cdec1610e2"
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Content-Length: 262144
    Content-Range: bytes 705201-967344/967345
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: video/mp4
]
```

Any help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I dont think fail2ban to be the proper tool for that. If its only for web traffic use the web server to filter.

Comment: Hello

I have to use it to allow only smartphone to navigate thrue vpn tunnelling

Peppe